# Connection Timeout when installing the app on phone

Tags: android, connection-timeout, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I don't know why I get connection timeout when installing the app on the phone. Here's what I get when working on this [manual](http://www.sitepoint.com/pebble-watch-development-javascript/):

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:jsapp1 mona$ pebble install --phone 72.33.18.249
[ERROR   ] Could not connect to phone at 72.33.18.249:9000. Connection timed out
```

and here's what I see in the Developers menu:
[image]
I can ping my phone:

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:jsapp1 mona$ ping  72.33.18.249
PING 72.33.18.249 (72.33.18.249): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 72.33.18.249: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=314.063 ms
64 bytes from 72.33.18.249: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=234.706 ms
64 bytes from 72.33.18.249: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=155.344 ms
64 bytes from 72.33.18.249: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=75.332 ms
```

My phone is Galaxy S6 Edge and I am using a MacBook Pro.

Comment: its a public ip address not ur phone private ip address .

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect your program in a different wifi situation. It solved the problem for me.

Comment: I'll accept this as answer if that worked later. I am using University WiFi and they are very strict. Now that I think I guess that could be the issue.

Comment: @MonaJalal I have had this type of issue before. Sometimes institutions impose certain restrictions that get in the way of what you are trying to do but pinging is still able to work. Switching to a different WiFi source should alleviate the issue, as long as the new WiFi source does not also share this type of restriction.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of university WiFi uses client isolation, which prevents CloudPebble from working. Getting on a standard WiFi network should resolve the issue.